# want to filter csv records on relatively large file

Tags: awk, apache-nifi

i have a simple flow, where i want to read a csv file and filter out record depending on value in some attribute.

file is relatively big, 1+gb, and i will not like to run it as a script (put,execute,get). I will prefer if content remains in FF.

previously, I have successfully used ExecuteStreamCommand processor for something like SED.

but with AWK, i am having hard time.

so data is in FF, and i want to filter on 12 column with value "29-12-2019"

following command works fine on unix shell => `gawk -F ',' '{OFS=",";if(toupper($12) == "29-12-2019") print;}' small.csv`

following is screenshot from my controller. AWK and GAWK, are behaving same way.

[image]

[image]

data looks like

```
SNO,SNN,PN,PPC,Product_Desc,Total,Status,New,NIT,Supplier_No,SN,SD,SVV
1,LC,967601,5.00E+12,GG 70,2,Active,,101703207,922,BT,23-12-2019,1
1,LC,967601,5.00E+12,GG 70,2,Active,,101703207,922,BT,24-12-2019,1
1,LC,967601,5.00E+12,GG 70,2,Active,,101703207,922,BT,25-12-2019,0
1,LC,967601,5.00E+12,GG 70,2,Active,,101703207,922,BT,26-12-2019,0
1,LC,967601,5.00E+12,GG 70,2,Active,,101703207,922,BT,27-12-2019,0
1,LC,967601,5.00E+12,GG 70,2,Active,,101703207,922,BT,28-12-2019,0
1,LC,967601,5.00E+12,GG 70,2,Active,,101703207,922,BT,29-12-2019,0
1,LC,967608,5.00E+12,GG 70,8,Active,,101731646,922,BT,23-12-2019,5
1,LC,967608,5.00E+12,GG 70,8,Active,,101731646,922,BT,24-12-2019,2
1,LC,967608,5.00E+12,GG 70,8,Active,,101731646,922,BT,25-12-2019,0
1,LC,967608,5.00E+12,GG 70,8,Active,,101731646,922,BT,26-12-2019,0
1,LC,967608,5.00E+12,GG 70,8,Active,,101731646,922,BT,27-12-2019,1
1,LC,967608,5.00E+12,GG 70,8,Active,,101731646,922,BT,28-12-2019,0
```

and resultant FF should contain just

```
1,LC,967601,5.00E+12,GG 70,2,Active,,101703207,922,BT,29-12-2019,0
```

**adding additional run screenshot**

different combination of command works fine on Unix/Linux. but somehow it doesn't run well with Nifi.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**tried couple of more type...now i am thinking, no way i can run this.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your attempt in form of code, could you please post samples of input and expected output in your post and let us know then.

Comment: added sample data as well. as filter is on 12th column, i am expecting 1 row as o/p

Comment: What stands FF for?

Comment: sorry, FF = flowfile

Comment: Why are you calling `toupper($12)` when $12 doesn't contain any letters? Also, you said `I have successfully used ExecuteStreamCommand processor for something like SED.` so edit your question to show an example of a sed command that works for you so we can see what kind of quoting you're using for it and then we can apply that to the awk script.

Comment: I would consider using the QueryRecord processor with a CsvReader, you can write SQL to filter the records

Comment: @BryanBende , correct. i have already done that. but issue with it, performance. consider this scenario as batched stream. and the time it is taking to do query record is more than time for me to receive next file. so things (FF) are piling up.

Comment: So you are getting better performance from ExecuteStreamCommand and AWK?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(check 2nd last field(`$(NF-1)` of lines).

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} $(NF-1)=="29-12-2019"'  Input_file
```

OR simply:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} $12=="29-12-2019"' Input_file
```

You need not to use `tolower` here because thats used  for making string values into small letters, not needed here.

Comment: your command worked well on unix. but not with Nifi, see my edits.

Comment: @RakeshPrasad, Honestly I never used apache nifi, seeing error it looks like `'` is cause of error? Can't we paste whole `awk` command in it? Or if not whole awk then try it only `BEGIN{FS=","} $(NF-1)=="29-12-2019"`?

Comment: @Rakesh from the images you posted showing error output it looks like your GUI tool is stripping the double quotes from the awk script and it doesn't allow single quotes around a script so try this: `awk "BEGIN{FS=\",\"} \$12==\"29-12-2019\""` or `awk \"BEGIN{FS=\\",\\"} \\$12==\\"29-12-2019\\"\"`

Comment: modified original post. no luck. now i am thinking or reading nifi implementation , rather than shooting in dark. will keep everyone posted.

Comment: @RakeshPrasad, Did anything work for you Rakesh; just curious to ask, we may also learn new thing too :)

Comment: i looked at NiFi code (product). and realized, anything we pass as argument cannot have double-quote (. they have explicit code to remove it. even if i ask them to skip it. In my view it is a bug, but may be they had different perspective in mind then they wrote it. I have an option to completely switch operation to UNIX and then continue in nifi. I may choose that. Thanks for keeping an eye.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the QueryRecord processor, it lets you query the flow file as if it were a SQL table, so you could do something like `SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE SD = "29-12-2019"`

Comment: I may switch to putfile, unix script, then getfile. as in my test, that consistently gave me somewhat better performance

Comment: Matt: can this be considered as shortcoming or bug in nifi processor?